# WCF scalability

Tags: c#, wcf

I need a good explanation how to configure my wcf InstantContextMode and ConcurrencyMode to be scalable as possible. 
I have a problems with scalability  because my wcf is using by more than 1000 clients in same time. Some of clients get timeout exception.
If I change InstantContextMode  to PerSession or PerCall my Processor has 100% usage - and this is another question - what Processor I need in this WCF (more than 1k call in same time)

Comment: so you have one server for more than 1000 clients? How about a load balancing service dividing the clients over more than one server

Comment: I'ts reading time!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323722(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Oscar It's always reading time!

Answer (score 0):

PerCall will create a new instance of your service class.

It depends on how much work is being done on each method call and important part is your Service constructor. Try to cache some data or objects across all calls (your service instances).

If you need to synchronize some stuff, use locks cautiously.

Comment: 95% connection is going same way - go to database, do some simple query and return simple result. Rest of them send some undefined data (from 0 to n KB). I dont think that I have to use some locks. And next thing - I cant cache anything because data retrieved from database is changing in real time